# Typescript: infer keyof base

Tags: typescript, generics

Lets say I have code like this:

```
interface KeysA {
  'propA1': number;
  'propA2': string;
}

class ClassA {
  public set<K extends keyof KeysA>(prop: K, value: KeysA[K]): void {}
}

interface KeysB {
  'propA1': HTMLDivElement;
  'propA2': HTMLButtonElement;
}

class ClassB {
  public set<K extends keyof KeysB>(prop: K, value: KeysB[K]): void {}
}
```

`KeysA` and `keysB` works like guards for set method. So `new ClassA().set('propA1', 'somestr')` throw error because type of `propA1` in `KeysA` is `number`. That's fine.

Now lets say I want to write following class:

```
class UniversalWrapper<
    TTarget,
    TItem extends TTarget extends {
      set<TK extends keyof infer TItem>(prop: infer TK, value: infer TProp): void
    } ? TItem : never > {
  public prop?: TItem;
  public constructor({target}: {target: TTarget}) {
  }
}

const w = new UniversalWrapper({
  target: new ClassA()
});
w.prop = '111'; // No type guard here!!!
```

Type of `w.prop` would be just `{}`. Why can't I infer base of `keyof` interface?

Let's assume I can't rewrite `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `KeysA` and `KeysB` because they come from third-party library.

Comment: Yeah .. that was my exact though to your other question. Can `infer` be used to extract a constraint. The answer would seem to be no.

Comment: Oh, now I think I'm giving up. Best solution i've found - use generic static methods instead of constructor. Thanks you for support! :-)

Comment: It's just my opinion that it can't be inferred.. there are people around here that do very interesting things with types... wait a while maybe they will surprize us :)

Comment: Looks like you want some higher kinded type functions which TypeScript currently [doesn't support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  The best you'll be able to infer for `w.prop` is probably something like `{ propA1: string | number; propA2: string | number;}`.